# Using MSBuild, how can you group .cs files with matching .g.cs files in another folder?

Tags: c#, msbuild, sourcegenerators

I have a `.NET 6` project where I want some *generated* files - somewhere in the "Generated" folder structure - to be grouped with their non-generated equivalents. See [dotnet/roslyn/issues/45645](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/45645) for some related concepts.

**How can you achieve this using** [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reference?view=vs-2022)? Key challenges include:

- Map all `Generated\**\*.g.cs` with their `*.cs` equivalents.
- If necessary: Copy all `.g.cs` files to their siblings' locations, allowing for grouping.
- Produce `DependentUpon` elements for the related files (`.cs` and `.g.cs`).
- If necessary: Remove the *copies* from compilation as they are already part of compilation.

**End result**

The end result should look like below. Note that removing, hiding or clearing the "Generated" folder is acceptable (if not preferable).

[image: End goal. Generated files appear together with non-generated equivalents.]

My understanding is that [DependentUpon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#none) is suitable for this, though (as far as I know) it will only work for files in the same folder.

So for our simple `Console` project, we would have something similar to this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- End goal (not hard-coded, obviously): -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Program.g.cs">
            <DependentUpon>Program.cs</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Steps to try this out**

1. Create a `.NET 6 Console` app.
2. Create a "Generated" folder in the root.
3. Add `Program.g.cs` in the "Generated" folder.
4. Put `MSBuild` magic in the `.csproj` file.

```cs
// program.cs
partial class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo();
    }
}

// program.g.cs
partial class Program
{
    public static void Foo() => Console.WriteLine("Generated");
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio will use `DependentUpon` to group files that are shown in the solution explorer. This doesn't change folders and files. In terms of 'grouping', `DependentUpon` is strictly about the solution explorer's display. `DependentUpon` is metadata and can be dynamically added to items. Is your question about how to dynamically add the `DependentUpon` metadata?

Comment: My question is about how to dynamically add `DependentUpon` for generated `.g.cs` files which have a "sibling" of `.cs` in another part of the folder structure. The main challenge is to get a list of all `.g.cs` that have a matching sibling in the `Compile` element.

Comment: Are you using an MSBuild task specific for the source generator? Does the task provide an output parameter of the generated files? (As an example the `Touch` task provides an output param of `TouchedFiles`.) If there is already an `ItemGroup` of generated files, then it should be used.  But if the `exec` task is being used to run a command, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example of matching the files and adding the `DependentUpon` metadata. However, the Visual Studio Solution Explorer window will not show the files as nested. Just adding the metadata when the project is run is not sufficient. The project file that is saved to the file system must be updated to include the `DependentUpon` metadata.

Regardless here is a working example of matching the files and adding the metadata:

```
  <Target Name="MatchAndAddDependentUpon">
    <!-- The file suffix for generated files -->
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Suffix>.g</Suffix>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Example data -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="aaa.cs;aaa$(Suffix).cs;bbb.cs;ccc.cs;ccc$(Suffix).cs;ddd$(Suffix).cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Create a set of generated files and a set of candiate source files (i.e. files not in the set of generated files) -->
      <Generated Include="@(Compile)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(Filename)').EndsWith('$(Suffix)'))" />
      <CandidateSource Include="@(Compile)" Exclude="@(Generated)" />

      <!-- Create Match as a cartesian product of Generated and CandidateSource; then prune the 'matches' that are false -->
      <Match Include="@(Generated)">
        <DependentUpon>%(CandidateSource.Identity)</DependentUpon>
        <DependentUponFileName>%(CandidateSource.Filename)</DependentUponFileName>
      </Match>
      <Match Remove="@(Match)" Condition="'%(DependentUponFileName)$(Suffix)' != '%(Filename)'" />

      <!-- Remove the items in Match from Compile; then include them but without the 'DependentUponFileName' -->
      <Compile Remove="@(Match)" />
      <Compile Include="@(Match)" RemoveMetadata="DependentUponFileName" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="@(Compile->'%(Identity) (DependentUpon %(DependentUpon))', '%0d%0a')" />
  </Target>
```

The output will look like the following:

```
MatchAndAddDependentUpon:
  aaa.cs (DependentUpon )
  bbb.cs (DependentUpon )
  ccc.cs (DependentUpon )
  ddd.g.cs (DependentUpon )
  aaa.g.cs (DependentUpon aaa.cs)
  ccc.g.cs (DependentUpon ccc.cs)
```

Note that the code handles the case where 'ddd.g.cs' exists in 'Compile' and 'ddd.cs', the expected parent, does not.

Comment: Cool! Cartesian product and stuff, that sounds like the right approach here!

I believe we just need to find the right time to call this target. I might have some notes regarding that.

Comment: I added to my answer to show the output and to highlight that, because the code is matching filenames and not making assumptions, when the expected 'parent' file is not in the 'Compile' set, 'DependentUpon' will not be set. I consider this to be more robust. Thanks

Comment: This is a good start, but it does not handle the specific case I'm trying to solve. The `g.cs` are not inte same folder as their `.cs` equivalents!


E.g.:
`<GeneratedFiles Include="Generated\**\*.g.cs" />`
How would you solve that?

Comment: The generated files must be in the same folder as their counterparts, so I guess the final step would be a move operation.

Comment: The `MatchAndAddDependentUpon` target uses `%(Filename)` to match. The file path is not considered. However you may want to move the files before invoking `MatchAndAddDependentUpon` so that the `DependentUpon` metadata can be added to the item with the final path location.

Comment: Yes, that's the tricky part. Given an *arbitrary* path with some filename `xyz.g.cs`, copy it to the directory where `xyz.cs` resides (must be part of `@(Compile)`). Ideally, multiple matches (very rare case) should be skipped and display a warning.